# How to install the pydelicious Python del.icio.us API?

Tags: python, api, windows-xp, delicious-api

I am running Python 2.4 on Windows XP and installed pydelicious API version 0.6. Upon running the install script I get `ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree`.

How to install it?

Which version of the API works with Python 2.4?

Where is the documentation? There is none on the download site http://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/ and the documentation folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementTree was not available in the standard [Python library until 2.5](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  It is available, though, as a separate install for [2.4](http://effbot.org/downloads/).

It looks like the pydelicious authors have even accounted for this.  From their [sources](http://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/source/browse/trunk/pydelicious/__init__.py):

```
try:
    from elementtree.ElementTree import parse as parse_xml
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.5 and higher
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse as parse_xml
```

Comment: OK, I got it working by installing elementtree from http://effbot.org/downloads/. Python complains "Feedparser not available, no RSS parsing.", but maybe I don't need that...

Comment: Fixed complaint "Feedparser not available." by downloading and installing feedparser from http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/.